# Connecting to local ips through one ddns with cssh

Tags: ssh, debian, lan, ddns

I'm using csshX (Mac equivalent of cssh, cluster ssh) and I want to use it for 5 computers.
Only one of the computers is a DDNS host, as I want to cssh remotely.
Currently I ssh into the DDNS host, and then use that to ssh to the other systems on the LAN - however I'm finding that tedious; hence cssh.
So I was wondering how you would go about setting up cssh to connect to all the systems.

Do I need to install cssh on the DDNS host and just run cssh off that?
My only concern is that the DDNS host is a headless setup (no monitor).

Basically I'm trying to see if this is possible:

```
csshX -l user hostaddr.domain.x user@ddnshostaddr user@10.x.x.x .. user@10.x.x.x
```

I understand that the sample command above wouldn't work, since it wont be able to resolve those local ip addresses, but I hope it kind of makes sense of what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have access to forward ports, you could forward a whole bunch of ports to the different machines so you can ssh directly to the hosts.
Forwarding port 2222,2223,2224,2225,2226 for example to port 22 of each machine.

```
hostaddr.domain.x:2221 ==> Host1:22
hostaddr.domain.x:2222 ==> Host2:22
hostaddr.domain.x:2223 ==> Host3:22
hostaddr.domain.x:2224 ==> Host4:22
hostaddr.domain.x:2225 ==> Host5:22
```

Then when you ssh, you would just connect directly to the hosts with -

```
csshX -l user hostaddr.domain.x:2221 hostaddr.domain.x:2222 hostaddr.domain.x:2223 hostaddr.domain.x:2224 hostaddr.domain.x:2225
```

Comment: Danke. I will try this tonight :)

Comment: It worked, however I was unable to specify port forwarding to different ports on my router. So to work around that I modified the sshd_config files to accept the different port, on each machine.